# Why does this appear on my serial monitor?

Tags: arduino

I wrote some code for Arduino Mega where

PINs 2 and 3 are initialized as output and set to output 2 LOW and 3 HIGH and
PINs 4 and 5 are initialized as inputs and are connected by wire 4 to 2 and 5 to 3.

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, INPUT);
  pinMode(5, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.flush();
}


void loop() {
  digitalWrite(2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
  Serial.write(digitalRead(4));
  Serial.write(digitalRead(5));
}
```

Why does my serial monitor look like this ?

> ,,,,,,,⸮l⸮l⸮l⸮l⸮l⸮h0⸮H⸮H⸮H⸮H⸮H⸮H⸮H⸮H⸮H,,,,,,,,,,,,⸮l⸮l⸮l⸮l⸮l⸮

Comment: Have you checked that the BAUD rate of your Serial Monitor is equal to the one you specified in your code (with `Serial.begin(115200);`)?

Comment: thanx that helped I didnt chack that. Now it displays squares tho. which is better than random stuff, but I would like it to display 1 and 0

Comment: use `Serial.print`. `write` sends a number and Serial Monitor interprets it as ASCII. `print` converts a number to text. see the basic examples in Arduino IDE

Comment: thx very much I love you :D - it works now

Comment: seems all-set for an answer now if PiThee or @Juraj would like to write one up

Answer (score 2):

Print class's method `write(byte)` sends a byte as it is and Serial Monitor interprets it as ASCII code of a character. In your case this are control characters with ASCII code 0 and 1.

You want to use Print class's `print(int)` which converts the number to text and sends characters to terminal.

```
Serial.write(97); // 97 is ASCII code of a
Serial.write('a');
Serial.print('a'); // uses print(char)
```

all print the character a, but

```
Serial.print(97); // uses print(int)
```

will print 97

`Serial` is an object of a class which is derived from `Print`. Specific class for `Serial` can be different on different Arduino platforms but they all enhance the `Print` class for output. There are many other classes in Arduino libraries which use `Print` as base class. For example `SoftwareSerial`, networking base class `Client` etc. For all of them you can use different versions of `write` to send bytes and [different versions](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-API/blob/master/api/Print.h#L63) of `print' and` println` to send text and numbers as text.